# Reinstalling python on CentOS to be able to use yum

Tags: python, centos, default, yum

I messed up big time and I removed the python package on a CentOS server. After then I realized yum was dependant on python and I could no longer use yum. I think I need to reinstall python to fix the problem. How can I do this without using yum?
I tried:

> sudo wget
>   http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64.rpm

then

> sudo rpm -ivh python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64.rpm

but I'm getting the error:

> error: Failed dependencies:   python-libs(x86-64) = 2.6.6-51.el6 is
>   needed by python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64  python < 2.6.6-52.el6 conflicts
>   with python-devel-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64

Please any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to download python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64.rpm instead.

Comment: I'm getting " package python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 is already installed
 file /usr/bin/python from install of python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64
 file /usr/bin/python2.6 from install of python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64"

Comment: That means you have had python installed on your system already.  Probably your yum problem doesn't come from python.  Can you post the error message while running yum?  Maybe you should check if you still have yum by "rpm -q yum".

Comment: when I'm doing sudo yum I have the error unable to execute /usr/bin/yum: Permission denied. When I'm doing rpm -q yum I have yum-3.2.29-43.el6.centos.noarch

Comment: You need to confirm the error message "permission denied" is form sudo or yum.  Can you do sudo on other commands?  This is the mode bits (permission) of yum in my system: "-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 801 Dec 17  2013 /usr/bin/yum".

Comment: That's really weird.  You should have privilege to do anything since you use sudo.  Have you tried to do yum after signing in as root?

Answer (score 0):

rpm link is not working any more...

you can use the command in centOS for sudo user like:

sudo yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64.rpm

without dependencies:

sudo yum install --nodeps   http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64.rpm

You do not need to download it.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing with --nodeps parameter.

```
# sudo rpm --nodeps -ivh python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64.rpm
```